# Ubuntu 22.04 Post Nvidia driver installation: Unable to run on non-Dell system

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, nvidia, 22.04

I've original Windows 11 laptop [Razer]. I setup dual-boot with latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Secure Boot enabled. After installing nvidia-drivers, I try to restart the laptop.

It fails to boot Ubuntu with following stack trace

```
ACPI Error: no handler for region [VRTC] [SystemCMOS]
ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECO.RTEC due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECO._REG due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
/dev/nvme0n1p7: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 229936/611232 files, 4288338/24413952 blocks
dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
```